# Prove that this sequence is between 0 and 1

Tags: analysis

Define a sequence by $x_1=1/3$ and $x_{n+1}=4x_n(1-x_n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ .

Prove that  $0\le x_n\le 1$ for all $n$;

I think I should prove it by induction. I don't know how to procede in the last step of the induction. Any sugestions.

Comment: [What is the maximum (and minimum) of the function $f\colon x\in [0,1] \mapsto 4x(1-x)$?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4x(1-x),+x%3D0..1&t=crmtb01) Once you have that, the induction is immediate.

Comment: If $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$, what is the minimum possible value of $x_n(1-x_n)$?  What is the maximum possible value?  What happens when you multiply by $4$?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of $x(1-x)$ with $x\in[0,1]$ is $1/4$ (which can be seen by setting the derivative to zero) and the minimum is 0 (since $x\geq x^2$ for $x\in[0,1]$). Hence, $0 \leq 4x(1-x)\leq 1$, for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Now, with $x_n \in[0,1]$ we see that $x_{n+1}=4x_n(1-x_n) \in [0,1]$ as well, so the proof is complete.